# Angular Directives: Declaration in different Module not recognized

Tags: angular, typescript, directive

The following situation:

module1 (universal) :

```js
  @NgModule({
    imports: [
      FormsModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      CommonModule,
      ...
    ],
    declarations: [
      // components cut
      LoadingSpinner,
      LoadableDirective,  // [appLoadable] selector
    ],
    exports: [
      // components cut
      LoadingSpinner,
      LoadableDirective,
    ],
    entryComponents: [ LoadingSpinner ]
  }
  export class UniversalModule { }
```

module 2 (loadable content module)

```js
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        ...
        UniversalModule,
        ...
      ],
      declarations: [
        LoadableContentComponent
      ],
    })
    export class LoadableContentModule { }
```

loadableContent.component.html

```html
    <div class="content" *appLoadable="isLoading"></div>
```

According to my understanding declaring + exporting the directive inside the `UniversalModule` and importing this module should give me the possibilty to use it inside the importing module's components, but when actually using it I get an error. 
e.g.

> Property binding appLoadable not used by any directive on an embedded
>   template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and
>   all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". Can't bind
>   to 'appLoadable' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Comment: Please share the code for `LoadableDirective`

Comment: Oh, while extracting the code, I found a typo which prevented it from working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While extracting the `LoadableDirective` code to post it I found a typo. Question is solved.